# Located in Frontend/Base file - how do i locate in local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, frontend, local.xml

I have reached desired behavior on frontend by blocking code in a base file:

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml**

```
<div class="block block-account">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Account'); ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul>
            </*?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
            </*?php $_index = 1; ?>
            </*?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
            <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
                <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
                <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                    <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i locate in **local.xml** to make adjustments to reach desired behavior on frontend? I realize I do not want to keep blocked code in base files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is excatly what you want but if your need is if you don't want to add your update in base file, if your theme has this file you have to do this update on it instead of the base one, otherwise you have to override it in a local: you copy the same path from:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml`

to:

`app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml`

You need to add nothing else in the XML, Magento get it from your current theme first, then default, then base one, what is called the **Theme fallback system**

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and I will keep that in mind for future reference however I'm not finding the same folder within the Theme. Is there another option?

Comment: I told you to create it in: app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml